# What's the meaning of strict reference flag in ECMA 5 262

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I was reading ECMA 5 262, and feel confused on the term "strict reference" in http://es5.github.com/#IsStrictReference:

> A Reference is a resolved name binding. A Reference consists of three components, the base value, the referenced name and the Boolean valued strict reference flag. The base value is either undefined, an Object, a Boolean, a String, a Number, or an environment record (10.2.1). A base value of undefined indicates that the reference could not be resolved to a binding. The referenced name is a String.

There's not much description on it. The only related operation on Reference is

> IsStrictReference(V). Returns the strict reference component of the reference V.

but no operation to set, neither description how we can decide the value.

I guess it must be related to the strict mode, but how can i tell what's the value for a specific Reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it's a property for references set to true when using references with `strict mode` in ECMAScript 5 (aka ES5) initialized. When `strict mode` is set, more operations will lead to errors (syntax, reference, for example initializing a variable without the `var` keyword). See the [MDN-documentation](https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Strict_mode) for more on `strict mode`.

[**edit**] based on comment
I think it's for the scope where `strict mode` is defined. So in

```
function strict()
{ 'use strict';
  // from here on and within the function
  // IsStrictReference is true
  showme = "Am I defined?";
  return "Hi!  I'm a strict mode function!  " + showme;
}

function nonstrict()
{ 
  // IsStrictReference is ... well, undefined I suppose, or false by default
  showme2 = "Am I defined?";
  return "Hi!  I'm NOT a strict mode function!  " + showme2;
}
strict(); //=> ReferenceError: showme is not defined
notstrict(); //=> "Hi!  I'm NOT a strict mode function! Am I defined?"
```

Executing  `strict()` throws a `ReferenceError`, but `nonstrict()` doesn't. If you had placed the `use strict`-statement outside the function blocks, executing both functions would throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: That could be one explanation. But there could be strict and non-strict code mixed in one program. So in which rule we can tell the value of this property, place in which the reference generated is strict code or not, or the base is created in strict code or not, or blabla. I'm really confused.

Comment: Hi @tdsparrow, see the edits. I advise you to (re)read the link to the MDN-documentation closely.

Comment: Thank you @Kooilnc, i took you advice, but reread the es5 again. I think i find the answer. It's explained very clearly in [Identifier Resolution](http://es5.github.com/#x10.3.1), `reference` will be created during the process `Identifier Resolution`, the surround code is strict or not will determinate the `strict reference` flag in reference.